# inner join on different qaunties

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

i have two Identical tables in my SQL database these tables consist of Item Code and QTY each.

I need to see which items in both tables that have different quantities AND  the items that

don't exist in the other table

**I tried using FULL OUTER JOIN ON ITEMCODE=ITEMCODE AND QTY<>QTY**

**IT IS NOT WORKING**

the result i am getting is something like that:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/nmb7yu

Comment: What does **IT IS NOT WORKING** mean? Do you get an error message? Wrong results? Something else? Please post a few rows of sample data (covering all possible cases) and desired results so we know exactly what you're after.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you can download the result set from the link i just added

Comment: At least say why the negative vote :@

Comment: Well, two people (not me) down-voted, and based on the up-votes on my comment, it is reasonable to assume that they didn't feel your question was very clear or included enough details to solve. The answerers guessed what you were expecting, but even the additional information about what you are currently getting does not indicate how that is different from what you *expect* to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  c.Code ,
        t1.Code ,
        t1.Qty ,
        t2.Code ,
        t2.Qty
FROM    ( SELECT    Code
          FROM      dbo.Table1
          UNION
          SELECT    Code
          FROM      dbo.Table2
        ) c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table1 t1 ON c.Code = t1.Code
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON c.Code = t2.Code
WHERE   t1.Code IS NULL
        OR t2.Code IS NULL
        OR t1.Qty <> t2.Qty
```

Since you have a test for inequality in the WHERE clause you're implicitly only including items that are in both tables. This way you include items that are in one table, but not the other, or have the difference in quantity.

Comment: WKordos answer is likely to perform better, just FYI. The union I provided will cause more reads due to the union & left outer joins.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from table1 a full outer join table2 b 
on a.code = b.code 
where a.qty <> b.qty or a.code is null or b.code is null
```

my lucky guess is that you filtered out rows where code column is null